# How can I set the font Times Roman in clean thesis?

Tags: fonts, times, cleanthesis

I am using clean thesis for writing a thesis. I want to know how to set the Times Roman font instead of sanserif font.

Comment: [Header and text font isn't changing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/306382) Substitute with `TeX Gyre Termes`.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: Actually a i want to change entire text including (chapter title, section,subsection) in times roman. so far i am not able to change in times roman.

Comment: Didn't my other answer help you?

Comment: yes,  is any other command available?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}%
\usepackage{cleanthesis}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\renewcommand{\helv}{\fontspec{TeX Gyre Termes}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\book}{\fontspec{TeX Gyre Termes}\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\tgherosfont}{\fontspec{TeX Gyre Termes}}
\renewcommand{\thesischapterfont}{\color{ctcolorblack}\huge\fontspec{TeX Gyre Termes}}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Walzing Wombat}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```